Issue with forwarding form values from child component to parent component using React Hook Form
I have a parent component PostForm and a child component CommentBox in my React application. The CommentBox component contains multiple textareas where users can input comments. I'm using react-hook-form for form management.
The problem arises when I try to submit the form from the PostForm component. Despite updating the posts state in the Comment Box component with the textarea values, the form data is not being forwarded to the parent component via register.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
// PostForm.js
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-tailwind/react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { CommentBox } from '../RecipeFrom/CommentBox';

const PostForm = ({ post }) => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm();

    const submit = async (data) => {
        try {
            // Log the form data to debug
            console.log('Form Data:', data);
            // You can proceed with further processing here
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error occurred:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
            <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center p-10 mt-8 '>
                <div className=' mb-4 flex flex-col justify-center gap-5 bg-blue-gray-50 backdrop-blur-sm py-8 rounded-lg px-6'>
                    <CommentBox
                        control={control}
                        register={register}
                    />
                    <Button
                        size='sm'
                        type='submit'
                        className=' bg-green-500'>
                        {post ? 'Update' : 'Submit'}
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
};

export default PostForm;


// CommentBox.js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    Textarea,
    Tooltip,
    IconButton,
    Typography,
    Button,
} from '@material-tailwind/react';

export function CommentBox({ control, register }) {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([{ text: '', image: null }]);
    const [stepCount, setStepCount] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Register each textarea individually
        posts.forEach((_, index) => {
            register(`commentBox[${index}].text`);
        });
    }, [register, posts]);

    const fileInputRefs = useRef([]);

    const handleAddMorePosts = () => {
        if (posts.length < 6) {
            setPosts((prevPosts) => [...prevPosts, { text: '', image: null }]);
            setStepCount((prevStep) => prevStep + 1); // Increase step count
        }
    };

    const handleDeletePost = (index) => {
        if (posts.length > 1) {
            setPosts((prevPosts) => {
                const newPosts = [...prevPosts];
                newPosts.splice(index, 1);
                return newPosts;
            });
        }
    };

    const handleAddImage = (index) => {
        fileInputRefs.current[index].click(); // Trigger file input click
    };

    const handleFileInputChange = (index, e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            // Handle file upload here
            setPosts((prevPosts) => {
                const newPosts = [...prevPosts];
                newPosts[index].image = file;
                return newPosts;
            });
        }
    };

    const handleTextChange = (index, e) => {
        const newText = e.target.value;

        setPosts((prevPosts) => {
            const newPosts = [...prevPosts];
            newPosts[index] = { ...newPosts[index], text: newText };

            console.log(newPosts);
            return newPosts;
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            {posts.map((post, index) => (
                <div
                    key={index}
                    className='flex w-full gap-5'>
                    <div className='w-full'>
                        <Textarea
                            label={`Step-${stepCount + index}`}
                            rows={3}
                            value={post.text}
                            onChange={(e) => handleTextChange(index, e)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='flex flex-col justify-evenly items-center'>
                        <Tooltip
                            placement='top'
                            className='border border-blue-gray-50 bg-white shadow-xl shadow-black/10'
                            content={
                                <Typography
                                    color='blue-gray'
                                    className='font-medium font-serif'>
                                    Add Image
                                </Typography>
                            }>
                            <IconButton
                                variant='text'
                                color='blue-gray'
                                size='sm'
                                onClick={() => handleAddImage(index)}
                                disabled={post.image !== null}>
                                Add Image
                            </IconButton>
                        </Tooltip>
                        <Tooltip
                            placement='top'
                            className='border border-blue-gray-50 bg-white shadow-xl shadow-black/10'
                            content={
                                <Typography
                                    color='blue-gray'
                                    className='font-medium font-serif'>
                                    Remove
                                </Typography>
                            }>
                            <IconButton
                                variant='text'
                                color='red'
                                size='sm'
                                onClick={() => handleDeletePost(index)}
                                disabled={posts.length === 1}>
                                Remove
                            </IconButton>
                        </Tooltip>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        type='file'
                        ref={(ref) => (fileInputRefs.current[index] = ref)}
                        style={{ display: 'none' }}
                        onChange={(e) => handleFileInputChange(index, e)}
                    />
                </div>
            ))}
            <Tooltip
                placement='top'
                className='border border-blue-gray-50 bg-white shadow-xl shadow-black/10'
                content={
                    <Typography
                        color='blue-gray'
                        className='font-medium font-serif'>
                        Add More
                    </Typography>
                }>
                <Button
                    variant='text'
                    onClick={handleAddMorePosts}
                    disabled={posts.length === 6}
                    color='green'
                    size='sm'
                    className='float-right'>
                    Add More
                </Button>
            </Tooltip>
        </>
    );
}


Despite the values being updated in the posts state in the CommentBox component, they are not being forwarded to the parent component when the form is submitted and give undefind value. How can I ensure that the form data is forwarded correctly to the parent component using react-hook-form?
enter image description here
enter image description here

IIRC the register function should spread its return into the input elements. I don't know why you have separate posts state that you are updating if you really just want to keep it in the form state/data.
